# Flutter Web: How do i disable "click to go back Button" using auto_route plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am Using the auto_route plugin for my flutter web project, which is working very fine. But After login, I want to prevent the user from returning to the login screen when the browser back button is clicked.
I have used WillPopScope but I have not achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
if (await _myController.canGoBack()) {
  if (requestUrl.contains('https://your login link')) {
   
    return Future.value(true);

  } else {
    _myController.goBack();
    return Future.value(false);
  }
} else {

  return Future.value(true);

  }
}
```